# Postman test throws error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProjectNumber' of undefined

Tags: javascript, java, soap, postman

I have written a Postman test script which is returning an xml in repsonse. But the test script is not running.

TestScript:

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
tests["TestCase"] = jsonObject.CreatePOReq.CreatePOReq.ProjectNumber === "3466703";
```

Response xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CreatePOReq ReturnStatus="Send to Vendor" GoetPONumber="806236" ProjectNumber="3466703">
    <line/>
    <header/>
</CreatePOReq>
```

Error :
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProjectNumber' of undefined

Console Log:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use the below code it will work definitely.

Use the '$' symbol instead of second 'CreatePOReq' value

```
 var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
 console.log(jsonObject);
 console.log(jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber);
 tests["TestCase"] = jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber === 
      "3466703";
```

Comment: I have another query, I want to set it to a global variable but when I do this I am not getting the actual value in the body of the request of another endpoint ->pm.globals.set(("ofs_projectNumber", "jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber"));
Then i try to use it in the request body of another Post endpoint ProjectNumber="{{ofs_projectNumber}}" .But this is not getting that value which I set earlier

Comment: Hi, we want to set it a value as a global variable,first, we need to id key(i,e. like: ofs_projectNumber as key)
please follow the below steps :
 -Click on the Eye icon in the post. add a variable with an empty value.
 -add below code in test in the body.  

                                                                    
                                                                    
 pm.globals.set("ofs_projectNumber", "jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber");
console.log(pm.globals.get("ofs_projectNumber"));

Comment: I tried that but not working -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593245/postman-not-returning-the-actual-value-in-console

Comment: please check stackoverflow.com/questions/59593245. I hope it will usefull

Comment: Yeah.I raised it..and it helped ..Thnx a lot for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK to repeat `CreatePOReq` in the third line of your TestScript?

```
tests["TestCase"] = jsonObject.CreatePOReq.CreatePOReq.ProjectNumber === "3466703";
```