# postman not returning the actual value in console

Tags: java, postman

I am trying to set up a global environment variable, but postman is not setting the value.
The script I wrote is

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
console.log(jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber);

pm.globals.set(("ofs_projectNumber", jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber));
console.log(pm.globals.get("ofs_projectNumber"));
```

But What I am getting in the console is very different - the last 2 lines should be identical, but it is not. What am I doing wrong

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here two curly braces are there. and  please below check attachment

```
     pm.globals.set(("ofs_projectNumber", jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber));
```

instead of use below.

```
     pm.globals.set("ofs_projectNumber", jsonObject.CreatePOReq.$.ProjectNumber);
```

[image]